# Custom Meta Query doesn't work the same on two site

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I'm building a query on a custom post type and some custom post meta.
Here is the query :

```
$meta_query = array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => '_thumbnail_id'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'offre_economie',
                'value' => 'pending',
                'compare' => '!='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'offre_app_partenaire',
                'value' => 1,
                'compare' => '!='
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => 'offre_expiration',
                    'value' => '',
                    'compare' => '='
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'offre_expiration',
                    'value' => date('Ymd'),
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'type' => 'DATE'
                )
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => 'offre_fin_evenement',
                    'value' => date('Ymd'),
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'type' => 'DATE'
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'offre_fin_evenement',
                    'value' => 'null',
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'offre_fin_evenement',
                    'value' => '',
                    'compare' => '='
                )
            )
        );
        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
```

It works perfectly fine on our testing site but when I put this last part on the final site :

```
array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'offre_fin_evenement',
        'value' => date('Ymd'),
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type' => 'DATE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'offre_fin_evenement',
        'value' => 'null',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'offre_fin_evenement',
        'value' => '',
        'compare' => '='
    )
)
```

When loading additional pages the query is so slow and sometimes it doesn't even load.
I've found some info on this question [Meta query terribly slow](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158898/meta-query-terribly-slow). But I still can't figure out why it works well on the testing site and not on the final one.

Comment: How many posts you have in final site ?

Comment: Post meta queries are fundamentally slow, that table was never designed for post searches, and they get slower as the size of the table increases. `NOT` type queries are also super slow as the database has to copy the table ( minus the bits you don't want ), so you get a full table copy, and a full row by row scan before the main part of the query can even run, all held in RAM so it can't run many of them at the same time, so no wonder this query is super slow. You should avoid `NOT IN`, and switch as many post meta as you can to a taxonomy, especially those that are just a flag/`1` value.

Comment: @AnoopD I have 646 posts in my test site and 654 in the final one.

Comment: @TomJNowell I see, I'll try with the taxonomy. But have you any idea why it works fine on my test site ?

Comment: probably because your test site has different data, and a much smaller database. Also test sites get less traffic than production, so a slow query has the entire resources of a server to run, but a production site has to share it across all visitors, so it's a scaling problem too. It's not enough for a site to load quickly once, you have to test how many people can load it at the same time. Looking at the query it does not surprise me that you are seeing these issues. You should be able to reduce your `meta_query` down to just the date fields, and use taxonomies for the rest

Comment: @TomJNowell So I've been looking around ways to improve my request but I don't see how taxonomy would fit in mine. From what I've understood taxonomy are like categories but my custom fields contain information like text, number, date, etc. And I'm mostly cheking if they exist in this query. I don't see how I could convert them to taxonomy (I don't know if it's something common but I'm quite new to this and I've found nothing that serve my case).

Comment: taxonomies are used to filter and group posts, you can have private hidden taxonomies that can be used to mark posts or act as flags, and some people already use categories and tags for this. I wouldn't recommend putting values you want to order by or do math and date arithmetic into taxonomies, taxonomies might be great for showing all posts flagged as 2015, but they can't be used to get all posts with a value between January 23rd 2014 and December 7th 2019.

Comment: For example, `offre_fin_evenement` is doing double duty here, why not have a term such as `has_event_offer` and `does_not_have_event_offer`. This would give the database an easy way to filter down the results so it has less work to do, and give you a much easier query, instead of checking for empty values, missing vaues, etc

Comment: And `offre_economie` should be a taxonomy, and `pending` should be a term in that taxonomy. Same with `offre_app_partenaire`, it's just a flag grouping posts into posts that have `offre_app_partenaire` and posts that do not have `offre_app_partenaire`, so just use 2 terms, one for posts that have it, one for posts that don't , e.g. `has_partner_offers` and `no_partner_offers`. You should also ask for all the statuses except pending. Asking for `A` `B` and `C` is cheaper than asking for everything that is _not_ `D`, the end result is the same but the performance difference can be massive

Comment: Either way, it seems most peoples answer to the age old question of should I use post meta, or should I use a taxonomy, is that _no lets just use post meta for everything and ignore the consequences_. Some things work best as post meta. Some things work best as terms in a taxonomy. The easy answer is if you need to find a post by this value, or filter/flag/search/group it then use a taxonomy, otherwise use post meta. Post meta is super fast when you already know the post ID, `get_post_meta` is very fast, but it's not built for searches. That's why taxonomy tables exist

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks a lot for explanations. Since this site has been running for some time before I start working on it I'll see what I can do to improve this.

Comment: Data migrations can be handled by WP CLI commands, most people refuse to do this because they don't know that a query and a loop can migrate all the data for them or think they have to do it all by hand